# CSS override Windows scaling (items smaller or larger)

Tags: html, css, windows, web

In windows you can change how big or small the icons and text looks. 
I recently found out that this affects CSS code too and sites look different in the same resolution!!

(as if CTRL +  is pressed)

Is there a way to override this and have your site look the same?

Comment: you might work with responsive/adaptive design concepts

Comment: that's my actual problem, my site is completely responsive, but using larger scale as a counteraction to bigger resolution, the site responds as well... i guess nothing can happen about that, but it's a wide problem!